# Custom User Interface

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-addons

How do I create custom user interfaces with a Minecraft Addon? All I see in `defaultreourcepack/ui` is these `.json` files:

> account_banned_screen.json
> account_transfer_error_screen.json
> achievement_screen.json
> add_external_server_screen.json
> adhoc_inprogess_screen.json
> adhoc_screen.json
> anvil_screen.json
> anvil_screen_pocket.json
> authentication_modals.json
> authentication_screen.json
> auto_save_info_screen.json
> beacon_screen.json
> beacon_screen_pocket.json
> blast_furnace_screen.json
> book_screen.json
> braze_screen.json
> brewing_stand_screen.json
> brewing_stand_screen_pocket.json
> bundle_purchase_warning_screen.json
> cartography_screen.json
> cartography_screen_pocket.json
> chalkboard_screen.json
> chat_screen.json
> chat_settings_menu_screen.json
> chest_screen.json
> choose_realm_screen.json
> coin_purchase_screen.json
> command_block_screen.json
> comment_screen.json
> confirm_msa_unlink_screen.json
> content_log.json
> content_log_history_screen.json
> convert_purchases_to_xbl_screen.json
> create_world_upsell_screen.json
> credits_screen.json
> custom_templates_screen.json
> day_one_experience_intro_screen.json
> day_one_experience_screen.json
> death_screen.json
> debug_screen.json
> dev_console_screen.json
> disconnect_screen.json
> edu_discovery_dialog.json
> emote_wheel_screen.json
> enchanting_screen.json
> enchanting_screen_pocket.json
> expanded_skin_pack_screen.json
> feed_common.json
> feed_screen.json
> file_upload_screen.json
> furnace_screen.json
> furnace_screen_pocket.json
> gamepad_disconnected.json
> gamepad_layout_screen.json
> game_tip_screen.json
> global_pause_screen.json
> grindstone_screen.json
> grindstone_screen_pocket.json
> hdr_calibration_screen.json
> holographic_postrender_screen.json
> horse_screen.json
> horse_screen_pocket.json
> host_options_screen.json
> how_to_play_common.json
> how_to_play_screen.json
> hud_screen.json
> immersive_reader.json
> inventory_screen.json
> inventory_screen_pocket.json
> invite_screen.json
> in_bed_screen.json
> item_detail_description_screen.json
> jigsaw_editor_screen.json
> late_join_pregame_screen.json
> library_modal_screen.json
> local_world_picker_screen.json
> loom_screen.json
> loom_screen_pocket.json
> manage_feed_screen.json
> manifest_validation_screen.json
> mob_effect_screen.json
> non_xbl_user_management_screen.json
> npc_interact_screen.json
> online_safety_screen.json
> pack_settings_screen.json
> patch_notes_screen.json
> pause_screen.json
> pdp_screen.json
> pdp_screenshots_section.json
> perf_turtle.json
> permissions_screen.json
> persona_common.json
> persona_screen.json
> play_screen.json
> pocket_containers.json
> popup_dialog.json
> portfolio_screen.json
> post_rating_screen.json
> profile_card.json
> profile_screen.json
> progress_screen.json
> rating_prompt.json
> realmsPlus_screen.json
> realmsPlus_sections
> realmsplus_upgrade_notice_screen.json
> realms_common.json
> realms_create.json
> realms_pending_invitations.json
> realms_plus_ended_screen.json
> realms_settings_screen.json
> realms_whitelist.json
> redstone_screen.json
> resource_packs_screen.json
> safe_zone_screen.json
> scoreboards.json
> screenshot_picker_screen.json
> screenshot_screen.json
> server_form.json
> settings_screen.json
> settings_sections
> sign_screen.json
> simple_inprogress_screen.json
> skin_pack_purchase_screen.json
> skin_picker_screen.json
> smithing_table_screen.json
> smithing_table_screen_pocket.json
> smoker_screen.json
> start_screen.json
> stonecutter_screen.json
> stonecutter_screen_pocket.json
> storage_management.json
> storage_management_popup.json
> store_common.json
> store_data_driven_screen.json
> store_filter_menu_screen.json
> store_gift_promotion_screen.json
> store_inventory_screen.json
> store_item_list_screen.json
> store_sales_item_list_screen.json
> store_search_screen.json
> store_sort_menu_screen.json
> structure_editor_screen.json
> sync_iaps_to_xbl_screen.json
> tabbed_upsell_screen.json
> test_anims_screen.json
> third_party_store_screen.json
> toast_screen.json
> token_faq_screen.json
> trade_2_screen.json
> trade_2_screen_pocket.json
> trade_screen.json
> trade_screen_pocket.json
> trial_upsell_screen.json
> ugc_viewer_screen.json
> ui_art_assets_common.json
> ui_common.json
> ui_common_classic.json
> ui_edu_common.json
> ui_holo_cursor.json
> ui_purchase_common.json
> ui_template_buttons.json
> ui_template_dialogs.json
> ui_template_tabs.json
> ui_template_toggles.json
> update_version.json
> win10_trial_conversion_screen.json
> world_conversion_complete_screen.json
> world_conversion_error_report_screen.json
> world_panorama_screen.json
> world_templates_screen.json
> xbl_console_signin.json
> xbl_console_signin_succeeded.json
> xbl_first_launch.json
> xbl_friend_finder.json
> xbl_optional_signin.json
> xbl_report_user.json
> _global_variables.json
> _ui_defs.json

What do they do? How can I change the UI of a screen with these files?

Comment: most of those are for screens like the settings and error messages and other ui

Comment: You can modify those files to modify the menus of the game, but I’m like 99% sure that adding the HTML UI stuff is different. I don’t really know, hope you find the answer the addon documentation is !

Comment: @Penguin But with those files, what is the _syntax_ to edit the menus?

Comment: @Penguin BTW the HTML documentation is for Behavior packs, not Resource packs.

Comment: ? You said you wanted a custom GUI, I now understand, I think the phrase you're looking for is "modifying a UI". What's the specific issue? The files contain the examples in them